# Changing voiceover readout to omit '...'

Tags: ios, accessibility

Ellipses '...' defined as marks or a mark indicating an omission of words or a pause is commonly used as a visual cue to indicate incompleteness.

E.g. 'Loading ...'

When voiceover is turned on on an iOS device - by default any text that includes an ellipsis will be read out.

i.e. 'loading ellipsis'

Should the voiceover read out be overridden with a new behaviour to omit the ellipsis?

A consideration is that if the user can see the text - the ellipsis will provides the visual cue. However if the user relies only on the voiceover readout they may need to infer the ellipsis or should this be explicitly read out?

Answer (score 1):

I think that omitting it altogether is not a good solution since the incompleteness cue is important to the user.

Saying out loud "loading ellipsis" is only marginally better - experienced users will get used to it and appreciate it, but it sounds pretty bizarre and can be very confusing in some  contexts.

I'd suggest that punctuation marks be represented by non-verbal auditory cues, and it would be great to develop an international standard for this (currently there isn't any that I've heard of). Some sort of short and clear sound, similar to the dialing pulses on rotary phones. E.g. a pulse would be a comma, a longer one a dot and three short ones an ellipses, something like that.

Comment: A non-verbal auditory cue would be great